# passing a array from url into a mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an url which is looking like following:

http://url/app/my.php?my=1,2&limit=2&lastid=0

Where the my paramater length can vary, but is always seperated by a comma. This i would like to add into a mysql query, which i've tried to do like following:

```
$limit = $_GET['limit'];
$lastid = $_GET['lastid'];
$my = $_GET['my'];


$all_news = $con->prepare("SELECT news.id, news.title, news.url, news.image_url, news.date, news.news_text, news.referer_img from news, team, contain WHERE team.id in (?) AND team.id = contain.team_id AND contain.news_id = news.id ORDER BY news.date DESC LIMIT ?, ?"); 
$all_news->bind_param("iii", $my, $lastid, $limit);
$all_news->execute();
$all_news->bind_result($id, $title, $url, $image_url, $date, $news_text, $referer_img);
```

I've tried both binding it as a string and int, but te $my array does not seem to work in the query? do i need to explode it and then implode the $my array? or what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to [parse_str()](https://php.net/parse_str) and [parse_url()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
$url = parse_url('http://url/app/my.php?my=1,2&limit=2&lastid=0', PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($url);
```

And access the `$my` later on

```
$all_news = $con->prepare("SELECT news.id, news.title, news.url, news.image_url, news.date, news.news_text, news.referer_img from news, team, contain WHERE team.id in (?) AND team.id = contain.team_id AND contain.news_id = news.id ORDER BY news.date DESC LIMIT ?, ?"); 
$all_news->bind_param("iii", $my, $lastid, $limit);
$all_news->execute();
$all_news->bind_result($id, $title, $url, $image_url, $date, $news_text, $referer_img);
```

Comment: well i know for a fact that it $my actually retrieve the 1,2 but it does not work when i add it into the query

Comment: it does not seem to make any difference however placing this WHERE team.id in (" . $my . ") works, but i guess its bad practice instead of using bind_param?

Comment: Well, could you var_dump the prepared query?